Why does Entity Framework return an empty collection instead of a null for a property?
I have an Entity Framework model that has the following property:
public List<MapInterestToVanType>? VanMapEventTypes { get; set; }

I then read the object using:
var @event = await dbContext.Events
    .Include(e => e.ApptShifts)
    .Include(e => e.Occurrences)
    .Include(e => e.Owner)
    .Include(e => e.Parent)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == updateEvent.EventId, stoppingToken);

This returns @event.Parent.VanMapEventTypes == an empty of List<MapInterestToVanType>().
If I add:
var @event = await dbContext.Events
    .Include(e => e.ApptShifts)
    .Include(e => e.Occurrences)
    .Include(e => e.Owner)
    .Include(e => e.Parent)
    .ThenInclude(o => o.VanMapEventTypes)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == updateEvent.EventId, stoppingToken);

It then returns @event.Parent.VanMapEventTypes with the expected 11 items in the  List<MapInterestToVanType>().
Why does it not return @event.Parent.VanMapEventTypes == null in the first call?

public class Organization
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public List<MapInterestToVanType>? VanMapEventTypes { get; set; }
    // lots of other properties

    public Organization(string uniqueId)
    {
        ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(uniqueId);

        Enabled = true;
        Private = false;
        Deleted = false;

        UniqueId = uniqueId;
        // initialize this because the data is in the Campaign table so logically its never null.
        Address = new Address();

        VanMapEventTypes = new List<MapInterestToVanType>();
    }
}

public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Organization Parent { get; set; }
    // lots of other properties
}

public class MapInterestToVanType
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string InterestName { get; set; }
    public string VanEventTypeName { get; set; }
}


I believe the list is created (always) when the object is constructed, but it is not populated - i.e., lazy loading (?). So its not null (the list object itself), but also just not loaded (the related entities that go in the list). In the second case you have of course explicitly loaded the list with the includes. Whether this is good or bad behavior - not sure.

Base reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/ Not clear to me if lazy loading happens by default or needs some special configuration.

@topsail I have never seen it do this. It is either null or, for a tracking DbContext, if the data is already read in, populated. I've never seen it create the collection but not populate it.

Hmm okay not sure then.

Is this VanMapEventTypes a foreign key relation on the entity (Event.VanMapTypes), or related to an an entity that is related to the entity (Event.X.VanMapTypes)?

Can you show the constructor of the Parent type?

@HenkHolterman - that was it - the constructor. Thank you. And if you write that as an answer, happy to accept it.

No, bu you can post a self-answer.

The issue is my constructor has:
VanMapEventTypes = new List<MapInterestToVanType>();

so event if there is no Include(e => e.VanMapEventTypes), it will still create the empty collection. I removed that line of code and now it works as I expected.

Although you declare MapInterestToVanTypes as nullable:

public List? VanMapEventTypes { get; set; }

You explicitly instantiate it to an empty list in the Organization constructor here:

VanMapEventTypes = new List();

If you are able to access @event.Parent here:

This returns @event.Parent.VanMapEventTypes == an empty of List()

Then you must have a non-null Organization object, which will contain at least an empty list, but never a null one.

You stole the answer from @HenkHolterman above. But as he is declining to answer it, you can. Please improve your answer as it is a bit non-sensical (it feels like an AI generated answer) and then I'll accept it.

There is nothing nonsensical or stolen...If you'll notice his comment is collapsed when you land on the page, thus I didn't see it.  I instead read your question, and found the issue.  I then highlighted the lines in your code to illustrate why you had an empty list.
